# AutoSelect in MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

**

### How can I call the API onfocus in autocomplete in mui? Which property help me to achieve this? I have used the selectOnFocus property but not achieved the requirement.

**

```
   <Autocomplete
          id="entry-description"
          freeSolo
          selectOnFocus
          handleHomeEndKeys
          disableClearable
          onChange={handleSelection}
          options={recentTimeTrackEntries}
          inputValue={description}
          getOptionLabel={(option: any) => {
            return option.description;
          }}
          renderOption={(props, option) => {
            const optionLabel =
              `${option.description ? option.description : ''}${
                option.projectName
                  ? (option.description ? ', ' : '') + option.projectName
                  : ''
              }${
                option.tags.length
                  ? option.tags.map((tag: FilteredTag) => tag.name).join(' ')
                  : ''
              }` || '-';
            return (
              <li
                {...props}
                key={option.id}
                data-entry={JSON.stringify(option)}
                value={option.id}
              >
                {optionLabel}
              </li>
            );
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <Stack direction="row" spacing={0.4}>
              <TextField onChange={handleChange} {...params} />
              {required ? <Typography variant="h4">*</Typography> : null}
            </Stack>
          )}
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `onOpen` prop.
And there is an example for it.

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#load-on-open

https://codesandbox.io/s/j8jnpe?file=/demo.tsx

Please check it.